# How to download an Html page and its internal files in android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, jsoup

I'm working on an application that needs to download the source of a web page from a link, with all the internal files, like images, css, javascript.

After, I will need to open this html in a webview, in offline mode, that's why I need to download everything from the page.

I'd download the images using JSOUP, but I haven't ideia how to link them into the downloaded html.

Could you give me some examples, or starting points where to look to start?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the html page you should have the `img` tags, additionally you know your file names. You could try scanning through the html page and replace the source paths of the images with your new ones. I have to add though, that depending on the size of the websites you are saving, your phones memory will be filled up pretty fast

Comment: Dunno if it'd be possible to run on Android, but [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) would be how I'd normally approach this problem. There's a couple of flags you can pass to wget that will make it do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, what you'll need to do (and what my app mentioned below does) is go over all the references links to additional  additional assets / images / scripts and so on, download them, and then change the HTML document to point to the local downloaded copy. Something like this, with Jsoup:

- Find all the `img` elements on the page,
- Get the location / url of the image file from the src attribute of the `img` elements (with `.attr("abs:src:)`),
- Download all of those images to a local directory
- Change each of the image elements src attribute values to point to the location of the downloaded image file, relative to where the main HTML file will be stored, eg with `.attr("src", "assets/imagefilename.png"")`.
- Do this for all other assets required by the page, eg. images, CSS, scripts, html5 video, and others. I also did some regex on the CSS (both linked and inline) to extract, download, and rewrite things like background image references and in the css. Webpages also have other linked things like favicons or RSS feeds which you might want too.
- Save your Jsoup document (with the modified URLs pointing to your downloaded versions of the assets) to file, by calling `.toString()` on it and saving the result to a file.

You can then open the local HTML file in webview, and, assuming you have done everything right, it will show with all images and assets, even offline.

---

I actually wrote an Android app which does exactly this: save a complete HTML file and all of the CSS / images / other assets to a local file / directory, using Jsoup.

See https://github.com/JonasCz/SaveForOffline/ for the source, specifically [SaveService.java](https://github.com/JonasCz/save-for-offline/blob/master/app/src/main/java/jonas/tool/saveForOffline/SaveService.java) for the actual HTML page saving / downloading code.

Beware that it's GPL licensed, so you have to comply with the GPL license if you use (parts of) it.

Also beware that it does a lot of things, and is quite messy as a result, (there's also no comments or documentation either...) but it may help you.

Comment: Man, that's awesome! Thanks a lot, I'll take ideas from your project.

Comment: Awesome that it helped you ! Let me know if you have any other questions @Jackcar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jsoup. IMO, it's a lot of work. On the other, you can consider [Crawler4j](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j).

There is a tutorial on their website. Have look to the example for [crawling images](https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/tree/master/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/imagecrawler).